# Configuring Azure Application Gateway for Multi tenant App service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-gateway

I have **application1.Azurewebsites.net** and **application2.Azurewebsites.net** and I want to use **Azure Application Gateway** , I followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-web-app) and I was able to do it for one application but there is no documentation on how I achieve the same for more than one app, I tried multisite setup as soon as I set it up i get 400 response from the application Gateway endpoint my back end pools shows healthy status.

For the Multiple Application Set up in Gateway.

```
BackEnd Pool
App Services -> app1 (BackEndpool1)
App Services -> app2 (BackEndpool2)


httpsettings
setting1 => port 80 , use appservices , customprobe (httpsettings1)
setting2 => port 80 , use appservices , customprobe (httpsettings2)


Listeners
Multisite => fronendport 80 => hostname = app1 (Listeners1)
Multisite => fronendport 80 => hostname = app2 (Listeners2)

Rules 
(Listeners1) -> (BackEndpool1) -> (httpsettings1)
(Listeners2) -> (BackEndpool2) -> (httpsettings2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid Me,I had missed the step of adding application Gateway's CName for app1 and app2 once I did that it started working

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same scenario but I don't know how to CNAME both apps to (app1 and app2)  to gateway name. ?